# Sanding motorbike bolts and abs sensor plates?

Tags: motorcycle, paint, yamaha, kawasaki, restoration

I want to do some cleaning up on my 2 motorbikes whilst in lockdown. I was just wondering do the manufacturers put any protective coating on bolts, or the abs sensor disc on the wheels?

As there is bits of rust on these so I want to ensure i'm not going sand off any protective coating?

I also have engine enamel, and I went a bit close the other day with a jet wash on the swing arm and took some paint off, can I dab some of this enamel on with a brush onto bare metal?

Bikes I have Yamaha R1 2007, Kawasaki Z1000r 2018.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the fasteners are made from stainless steel, which yours are likely not since you said that the have rust on them, then they will have some kind of anti-corrosion coating.

This coating could be zinc or they could be electro plated

For example read - https://www.bhamfast.com/electroplating-fasteners/

It would therefore be unwise to sand them down unless they are that bad that there is no other option, but you will need to protect them with some paint.

You could replace them with new bolts, or even clean them and re-plate them yourself.  There are videos on YouTube showing how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for this, a lot of the bolts on the R1 are rather rusty due to it's age, so might be worth giving that a go with them. The Kawasaki is much newer so not as bad, I could try clean them in other ways.